# Keras with Tensorboard: No scalar data was found

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I feel like this is a very simple problem but I just cannot find the problem even after looking online. I am trying to have the tensorboard display graphs for the loss and accuracy.

This is the line of code that trains the neural net with the Tensorboard as a callback

```
unet.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 2, batch_size = 256, shuffle = True, validation_data = (x_test, y_test),callbacks = [TensorBoard(log_dir = 'tmp/unet', histogram_freq = 0, write_graph = True, write_images = False)])
```

After using the below command in terminal it says there is no scalar data found.

```
tensorboard --logdir=.../tmp/unet
```

Comment: If you put histogram_freq = 1 it shows the histogram tab?

Comment: Also can you post the create_model function?

Comment: When launching tensorboard try a full path to your logdir rather than a relative one, that works for me when I get this error.

Comment: model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=conv10)

model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 5e-3), loss = "binary_crossentropy")

Comment: I figured it out. It was a problem with the tensorflow version

Comment: what exactly was the version problem?  @Punisher